# "Insert" is always on in my Vista command prompt

Tags: command-line, windows-vista

When I start command prompt (cmd.exe) in my Vista Business 32-bit, it acts as if the *Insert* key was toggled, so whatever I type overwrites the characters under the cursor. I can turn it off by pressing Insert, but whenever I move into a new line (next command), Insert turns back on.

It's incredibly annoying and unfortunately I don't know how this happened, but I'd like to turn this mode off.

Comment: Happens in Windows 7 as well. I miss Linux. This and many other crap just doesn't happen in Linux.

Comment: And seems to be happening to me with Windows 10 as well. Ugh.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

At the extreme top left of most windows, there is a small box which - when clicked - opens the system menu.  Usually this menu contains nothing much more than Move, Size, Minimize and Maximize.  For command windows, it also includes **Properties**.  Select that, go to the **Options** tab and make sure that **Insert mode** is enabled.  Click OK to save your changes, and when prompted, choose "Save properties for future windows with same title".

You can also do this by right-clicking on the shortcut you use to open the command window and selecting **Properties**.

Comment: ah, thanks. I had Insert mode disabled, but it's apparent that *Insert Mode* does exactly the opposite of what I thought.